# Create only one spreadsheet for storing data in doPost, without duplication

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google App Script to add data to a spreadsheet from an external source that POSTs to the script. I want to create the spreadsheet if it has not been created already and then append the data to the same spreadsheet. However, every time the external source POSTs, the script duplicates the spreadsheet and I get hundreds of files created in my Drive.

I've tried checking if the spreadsheet is active and not null but as I am a total beginner I'm not really sure what I am doing and can't figure out how to make the script identify the created spreadsheet and not duplicate itself.

```
function doPost(e)
{
var sl = e.parameter;
url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');

 var payload =
   {
     "List":sl


   };



   var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload
   };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

if(SpreadsheetApp.getActive() != null) 
{

   //append data
}

else
{

  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Finances");
  var ssUrl = ssNew.getUrl();
  ssNew.setActiveSpreadSheet().openByUrl(ssUrl);

}


}
```

How do I create only one instance of the spreadsheet and add data to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script triggered by `doPost` has no concept of Active Spreadsheet (even if it's bound to a spreadsheet). You should use openByUrl or openById to access any spreadsheets. The easiest way is to create a spreadsheet yourself, and use its URL in the openByUrl command in the script.

If for some reason you don't want to create a spreadsheet manually, then keep track of the creation using Script Properties:

```
function doPost(e) {
  // some stuff 
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ss, ssId = props.getProperty('ssId');    
  if (ssId) {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  }     
  else {  
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Finances");
    props.setProperty('ssId', ss.getId());
  }
  // access/create some sheet in "ss" and append data
}
```

The logic here is to get the Id from script properties and open the spreadsheet with that Id, unless it's null, in which case a new spreadsheet is created and its Id is stored.

(I don't understand why your doPost function makes a Post request itself, but that's beside the main point.)

Comment: The post was a callback to the external source for debugging. Your suggestion worked thank you so much!